# exec.Command with bash -c does not return stdout

Tags: bash, go

Executing the following program, `out` is an empty slice of type `[]uint8`.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "bash", "-c", "python3", "-c", "print('hello')")
    out, _ := cmd.Output()
    log.Println(out)
}
```

However, if I run without `bash -c`, I get the expected output.

This is a trivial example where `bash -c` isn't needed, but in the real world, my app is invoking a python script which imports several packages, and without `bash -c`, I get "module not found" errors from python.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I capture the stdout contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash -c` should be followed by **one** string argument with the command to execute, then bash will do the argument processing.

```golang
cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "bash", "-c", "python3 -c 'print(\"hello\")'")
```

Comment: Doesn't OP want to capture the content of stdout? Though the suggestion is right, I still don't see a valid output in `out`, maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: @Inian: if you don't have an output, check your error value and stderr. The exec example here is correct.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!